# Duplicate a CSV column in Bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I have an issue where a client needs to duplicate a column in a CSV file. The values are always going to be identical and unfortunately our API doesn't allow for duplicate columns to be specified in the JSON.

For example I have the following column structure and values:

```
Name, Surname, City, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

Now I need to duplicate City so the output should be:

```
Name, Surname, City, City Again, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

The column needs to be placed after that which will be duplicated. The value is also dependent on this first column.

Comment: The value in the case here is Johannesburg. The first example it appears once under City. It's duplicated in the second example under City Again

Comment: So, in the first record, containing your column names, $3 != $4. How do you want to generate your headers? (I don't see the code you're using to try and do this in your question, please add it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `City` will always be located at column 3, the [cut](https://ss64.com/bash/cut.html) and [paste](https://ss64.com/bash/paste.html) commands can be utlized. For example:

```
csv=path/to/somefile.csv
echo "$(paste -d',' <(cut -d',' -f1-3 $csv) <(cut -d',' -f3- $csv))" > "$csv"
```

*Notes:*

1. The `path/to/quux.csv` part, which is assigned to the `csv` variable, should be replaced with the actual path to your `.csv` file.
2. The new content which includes the duplicated `City` column is written back to the same source file.
3. The `<(...)` part is known as *process substitution* and is typically used when piping data is not possible. A good explanation of it can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1059781/what-exactly-is-in-bash-and-in-zsh#answer-1060002).

Comment: This is very inefficient for big files as the whole file has to be read *three* times or slightly more than that!  The [`awk`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44182774/6862601) solution is far better as it reads the file only once.

Comment: @codeforester - Thanks for commenting. Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by _"very inefficient for big files"_. The metrics I obtained, in terms of completion time, revealed that running the solution I provided across a `.csv`  containing one million rows with five columns, averaged at 12.2 seconds. Whilst the _awk_ solution averaged at 13.7 seconds using the same data set. All times for both solutions were inclusive of  the time taken to write the results back to disk . What metrics are you basing your comment on? Is the _awk_ solution particularly memory efficient or something?

Comment: In addition to the `awk` approach taking slightly longer to complete than the solution I provided, on average the `awk` solution also consumed more real memory too. The `awk` solution consumed  283Mb of memory, whilst this solution consumed 190Mb. These metrics were obtained whilst running the same test conditions mentioned in the previous comment. I can only conclude from these metrics that the comments regarding my solution being _"very inefficient for big files"_, are somewhat misleading and inaccurate.

Comment: If you use a big file iin input as @codeforester says.then difference in behavior will be evident. I created a csv file with 25 million lines and ran this command. It didn't complete even after an hour, didn't write any line in the output file and I had to kill the shell whereas `awk` command took 58 sec to complete.

Answer (score 8):

`awk` can handle this easily:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {$3 = $3 OFS $3} 1' file.csv

Name, Surname, City, City, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

Note that this does the job in single and shorted command that is easy to read and is far more efficient than pipeline command that involves calling `cut` twice and then a `paste.

As @codeforester  rightly commented below, `cut` doesn't let a column be repeated in the output; it is used for stripping out a value.

Comment: Yep, that would be the way to do this if it were an awk question instead of a bash question. :-)

Comment: OP may not be aware of prowess of `awk` :)

Comment: Very elegant and efficient.  @anubhava - the point that `cut` doesn't let a column be repeated in its output could be noted in your answer.  From `man cut`: **If a field or column is specified multiple times, it will appear only once in the output.**

Comment: Thanks @codeforester for kind words. I have added this in my answer as well.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the tools of awk and cut. I'm mainly a PHP developer but our current project demands bash scripts to keep consistency across all of them. There's going to be about 10k lines that runs daily so I'll try all the solutions with test files. Thanks so much guys!

Comment: `cut` and `paste` are also external utilities same as `awk` that are found on every Unix/Linux system.

Comment: It is because `cut/paste` solution involves forking sub-shell twice + calling 3 external utilities vs a call to single external utility `awk`.

Comment: I created a csv file of `25000000` lines. `awk` command took 58 sec to finish. And `cut+paste` is still running for last 25 minutes.

Comment: awk is the greatest.

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I wrote a bash function to insert array elements:

```
function array_insert {
    # options: arrayname index [value]
    if ! declare -p "$1" 2>/dev/null | grep -q '^declare -a'; then
        printf '%s: not an array: %s\n' "$0" "$1" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    local -n source="$1"
    local -a indices=( "${!source[@]}" )
    for ((i=${#indices[@]}-1; i>=$2; i--)) ; do
        source[$((i+1))]="${source[$i]}"
    done
    if [ -n "$3" ]; then
        source[$2]="$3"
    fi
}
```

With this function loaded, you might do the following:

```
while read line; do
  IFS=, declare a=( $line )     # assign the line's fields to an array,
  array_insert a 3 "${a[2]}"    # insert the column in this line,
  o=$(printf '%s,' "${a[@]}")   # assemble your output,
  printf '%s\n' "${o%,}"        # remove the trailing comma.
done < input.txt
```

For me, this provides the following output using your input:

```
Name, Surname, City, City, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

Note that in bash, arrays are indexed from `0`, so `${a[2]}` is the third column.

Answer (score 0):

below is Small script which took two input

1. File Name
2. Column name 
   and it will duplicate mention column

Below is Script

```
echo "Enter  CSV File  name "
read fileName

echo "Enter Column name to be duplicated "
read columnName


columnNumber=`head -1 $fileName | awk -v RS="," "/$columnName/{print NR;}"`     #Identify Column number using column name
totalNumberOfColumn=`head -1 $fileName | awk -F',' '{print NF}'`                #identify total number of column

str=""                                                                          #Create empty variab str to print column number in awk
for ((i=1;i<=$totalNumberOfColumn;i++));
do
str="$str \$$i\",\""
        if [ $i == $columnNumber ]
        then
        str="$str \$$i\",\""
        fi
done


awk -F',' "{print ${str}}" $fileName  | sed 's/,$//g'                           #Print all column inculding duplicate column
```

below is content of file,  file name is **data.csv**

```
:cat data.csv
Name, Surname, City, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

Output 1 for Duplicating column **City**

```
:bash script.sh
Enter  CSV File  name
data.csv
Enter Column name to be duplicated
City
Name, Surname, City, City, Age, Job
John, Doe, Johannesburg, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```

Output 2 :  for Duplicating column **Name**

```
:bash script.sh
Enter  CSV File  name
data.csv
Enter Column name to be duplicated
Name
Name,Name, Surname, City, Age, Job
John,John, Doe, Johannesburg, 28, Technical Support
```